# showSemanticsDebugger does not work anymore

Tags: flutter, semantics

When I set `showSemanticsDebugger` to `true`, it should show the semantics tree representations, it worked fine about 2 months ago, but it's not anymore. I suspect it's an issue related to the latest version of the Flutter SDK.

Does anyone face the same issue?

Here's the output of flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.5, on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS 6.2.0-39-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

Comment: I've got the same issue and not sure if this is just my issue, or Flutter's. Wondering if you got it to work without the accessibility_tools package?

Comment: @DominikRoszkowski I have not tried to remove the package, it's been doing a great job since then, and I think I will need the extra functionality it provides very soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [accessibility_tools](https://pub.dev/packages/accessibility_tools) package magically fixed the issue and showed the proper semantics representation